# Build gcc from sources - GLIBC

Tags: linux, gcc

we have old Linux distribution and the vendor doesn't support its updates. We want to build our c++ code with a modern compiler, for that we are building GCC compiler from sources (something very similar to https://github.com/darrenjs/howto/blob/master/build_scripts/build_gcc_10.sh)

Now the problem is that we can not deploy the executables because users' machine do not contain libstdc++.so.6 for this GLIBC. Is there a way to compile GCC and make it based on old local GLIBC that the vendor provides?

[EDIT]: After build my executable of xenenterprise 8.0.0 with GCC 10.1.0 that was built from sources:

```
[root@xen8 sandbox-gcov]# ldd build/main
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffddf9fd000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /var/opt/gcc-10.1.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb82155f000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb82125d000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /var/opt/gcc-10.1.0/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb821045000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb820c77000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb82192c000)
```

Then got error on another machine with native GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44):

```
[root@xen8-1 sandbox-gcov]# ldd build/main
build/main: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by build/main)
build/main: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by build/main)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffeec5fe000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f92099db000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f92096d9000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f92094c3000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f92090f5000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9209ce3000)
```

Comment: Last time I compiled GCC from source code (a week ago) I got a `libstdc++.so`

Comment: What exact old distribution do you have? **On what computer hardware?** Can't you get a [Debian](https://debian.org/) or a source distribution like [Gentoo](https://www.gentoo.org/)? Why?

Comment: You got some things confused here. Glibc is the C standard library implementation and libstdc++ is the C++ standard library implementation. Glibc is not shipped with GCC. Can you clarify where exactly the version mismatch issue is and how it manifests to you?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have added more details

Comment: You generally cannot build against a newer version of libstdc++ (included in GCC) and then use it on a system with an older version's `.so`. If you compile the whole program with the new GCC (no other C++ libraries that were compiled with the old GCC) then it will probably be fine to just link with `-static-libstdc++`. If you have C++ libraries that you can't rebuild with the new GCC it can become complicated.

Comment: Also, note that nothing in your edit talks about glibc. (If you see `glibcxx` somewhere, that's not related)